# Trying to build a tic tac toe game in Python, stuck on the "AI"

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to programming and I've been trying to build a tic tac toe game that lets you play against an "AI". Everything but the AI seems to work.

The way I did it is that when it is X's turn (the player), python asks for input to get the player's move, and when it is O's turn (the AI), python uses the tictactoe_ai() function to decide on O's move.

As of now, the tictactoe_ai() only checks if there is a line of the same symbol that is about to be completed, so if it finds XX_, it would play XXO, and if it finds, O_O, it would play OOO. Same logic with diagonal and vertical lines. If it does not find such a pattern, it plays a random available move. I know the logic behind the AI can be upgraded, but I'm only trying to get it to work right now

The problem is that the tictactoe_ai() function works for the 2-3 first moves, it picks random spots effectively when it has to and can complete a line once, but after that, it either doesn't play at all or plays over an "X". I have no idea why it starts acting weird because the if-statements make sense to me and trigger/don't trigger at the wrong times

Here's the tictactoe_ai() function which uses the tic tac toe board as a dictionary (for instance, "top-L": "X"):

```
def tictactoe_ai(game_board):
    if game_board["top-L"] == game_board["top-M"] != " " or game_board["bot-R"] == game_board["mid-R"] != " " or game_board["bot-L"] == game_board["mid-M"] != " " and game_board["top-R"] == " ":
        game_board["top-R"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-L"] == game_board["top-R"] != " " or game_board["bot-M"] == game_board["mid-M"] != " " and game_board["top-M"] == " ":
        game_board["top-M"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-M"] == game_board["top-R"] != " " or game_board["bot-L"] == game_board["mid-L"] != " " or game_board["bot-R"] == game_board["mid-M"] != " " and game_board["top-L"] == " ":
        game_board["top-L"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-L"] == game_board["bot-L"] != " " or game_board["mid-M"] == game_board["mid-R"] != " " and game_board["mid-L"] == " ":
        game_board["mid-L"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-L"] == game_board["bot-R"] != " " or game_board["top-R"] == game_board["bot-L"] != " " or game_board["top-M"] == game_board["bot-M"] != " " or game_board["mid-L"] == game_board["mid-R"] != " " and game_board["mid-M"] == " ":
        game_board["mid-M"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-R"] == game_board["bot-R"] != " " or game_board["mid-L"] == game_board["mid-M"] != " " and game_board["mid-R"] == " ":
        game_board["mid-R"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-R"] == game_board["mid-R"] != " " or game_board["bot-M"] == game_board["bot-L"] != " " or game_board["top-L"] == game_board["mid-M"] != " " and game_board["bot-R"] == " ":
        game_board["bot-R"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-M"] == game_board["mid-M"] != " " or game_board["bot-L"] == game_board["bot-R"] != " " and game_board["bot-M"] == " ":
        game_board["bot-M"] = "O"
    elif game_board["top-L"] == game_board["mid-L"] != " " or game_board["bot-M"] == game_board["bot-L"] != " " or game_board["top-R"] == game_board["mid-M"] != " " and game_board["bot-L"] == " ":
        game_board["bot-L"] = "O"
    else:
        while True:
            play = random.choice(board_choices)
            if game_board[play] != " ":
                continue
            game_board[play] = "O"
            break
```

Here is the code that's active while it is O's turn:

```
while o_turn:
    tictactoe_ai(board)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print_board(board)

    if draw(board) and not game_over(board):
        print("It's a draw")
        break

    if game_over(board):
        print("O wins")
        break

    x_turn = True
    o_turn = False
```

Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/r8kvcJLw

I would greatly appreciate any help or any criticism towards my code overall, thanks a lot!

Comment: Always use parentheses to group your conditions when you mix `and` and `or`, since the default precedence may not match your intent. I suspect that's the problem in some of your `if` conditions.

Comment: Using a list of lists for the game board will probably make things easier than a dictionary, since you can then loop over rows and columns easily.